# Opening Visual Studio with a specific configuration and platform

Tags: devenv

From the command line, I would like to open Visual Studio into a specific platform and configuration (Note that this is *not* to build it, just to open the solution file)

I'm aware of the /Command switch, but I'm unaware of a command that can satisfy both Build.SolutionPlatforms and Build.SolutionConfigurations at the same time.

I also do not know how to chain together commands, or group them into a singular command.

I'm currently using `devenv %~dp0.\Setup.sln /Command "Build.SolutionConfigurations Release" /Command "Build.SolutionPlatforms Win32"` (currently not working)

I would expect (after executing the cli command) for Visual Studio to open with the appropriate platform and configuration settings.

Comment: I am looking for solution for this